# How to draw Pie Chart Manually?

Tags: android

I need to draw the Pie Chart Manually .I need some basic Ideas to do that.Can anyone help Me ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt/Pie.html) is an example in Java (not for Android). You could easily port it for Android by using a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) instead of Graphics2D object. Instead of fillArc for example, you would use [drawArc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28android.graphics.RectF,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

Answer (score 3):

```
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         DemoView demoView=new DemoView(getBaseContext());
         setContentView(demoView);
      }

     private class DemoView extends View{
       public DemoView(Context context){
        super(context);
       }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        RectF mBigOval = new RectF(40, 10, 280, 250);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        DashPathEffect dashPath = new DashPathEffect(new float[]{5,5}, (float)1.0);
        PathEffect path=new PathEffect();
        p.setPathEffect(path);
        p.setStyle(Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        p.setColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawArc(mBigOval, 0, 360, true, p);
        p.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawArc(mBigOval, 0, 240, true, p);


        invalidate();
    }
}
```

try this code

Answer (score 0):

Create your own custom [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) class and implement the `onDraw` method to draw the chart using [`ArcShape`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/shapes/ArcShape.html).

You can then include your chart component in a layout just as you would one of the built-in components.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a library to do what you are looking for (https://github.com/saulpower/ExpandablePieChart).